# ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB vs GL20.glDeleteShader to remove shader?

Tags: lwjgl

I've created a shader object using `ARBShaderObjects.glCreateShaderObjectARB`and I'm wondering exactly how I'm suppose to remove said shader.

It seems both `ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB` and `GL20.glDeleteShader` can do this.

I'm leaning towards `ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB` since I created the shader using the `ARBShaderObjects` set of classes.

Do both of these work?

In this case is one prefered or different from the other?

Sorry for general LWJGL / OpenGL noobiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the extension function to create an object, then you *must only* use those extension functions to manipulate that object. So if you use `ARBShaderObjects.CreateShaderObjectARB` to create it, then you must use `ARBShaderObjects.glShaderSourceARB` to give it source strings, `ARBShaderObjects.glCompileShaderARB` to compile it, `ARBShaderObjects.glAttachObjectARB` to attach it to a program, and `ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB` to delete it.

Remember: the return type of `glCreateShaderObjectARB` is `GLhandleARB`, which is a *pointer*, not a `GLuint` like the return value of `glCreateShader`. So they don't even use the same object type interface. The only functions that work with the ARB_shader_objects objects are those that explicitly say so. Which basically means those from that extension.

Also, there is no guarantee that you can compile any GLSL versions other than 1.10. The extension only guarantees support for that version, no others.

Basically, there is no reason to write code for this terrible 10+ year old extension. If you want to support hardware that has some shader functionality that isn't GL 2.0-capable, then use ARB_vertex/fragment_program.